# Color Picker Readonly

Tags: angular, readonly, color-picker

I want the color field readonly and fire a click event is there any way? currently i'am doing this

```
<input type="color" value="#9400D3" (click)="onClickColor('#9400D3')">
```

the click event is working but the color picker id also appearing which should not

Comment: What you exactly want, can you explain bit more?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example in stackblitz, this helps the SO community to better answer your question [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I dont want the color picker to come just wanna fire the click event on this input field @PardeepJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your input in a div and listen to clicks on this div:

```
<div (click)="onClickColor('#9400D3')">
    <input type="color" value="#9400D3" disabled>
</div>
```

This way the input is disabled but you can 'click' on it.